# Is it possible to test against the release version of your app with Android Gradle plugin?

Tags: android, testing, gradle

When I use the 'gradlew connectedCheck' command it always build the debug version and test against the debug version of my app. Is it also possible to test against the release version of my app?

I want to enable proguard and want to make sure that it doesn't filter anything out that is needed during runtime.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can only test against a single build type right now (though that may change).

To set the build type to test against:

```
android {
    testBuildType "release"
}
```

You could set this dynamically through a env var to not have to edit build.gradle all the time.

Comment: how do you change it through a env var? Even though I dynamically change the testBuildType property it always assembles the original type set at authoring time. e.g. :app:assembleReleaseTest instead of :app:assembleQATest

Comment: Hi, how to run all androidTests before a release from gradle? Is there any way?

Comment: Does this generate a different gradle task? I see that by default I have `connectedAndroidTest` and `connectedDebugAndroidTest`. Does the first one run both release and debug tests? If I apply your suggestion, do I instead have a `connectedReleaseAndroidTest` task?

Comment: @tir38 `testBuildType "release" ` will enable you test release version of androidTest. When you run `connectedAndroidTest`, it will trigger either `connectedDebugAndroidTest` or `connectedReleaseAndroidTest` respect to your `testBuildType` configuration, but during the runtime, you only have ONE testBuildType, either debug or release.