# How can I compile Espresso UI Tests into a release?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso, android-testing

I'm currently trying to add Espresso tests into a *release* APK. In our case we have to test on what's *actually* being released so the UI tests have to be included in the release.

So my primary question is: How is this best accomplished? Research on the internet gave me no result so far.

I already tried changing `androidDebugTest` in the build script to `compile`:

```
compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

And also here:

```
compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

But after calling

```
./gradlew assembleRelease --info --debug
```

I get this error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/annotation/Generated.class
...
BUILD FAILED
```

Furthermore usually there are two gradle tasks `assembleDebug` and `assembleDebugAndroidTest` to work with Espresso. But what are doing with a release build as there is no `assembleReleaseAndroidTest` task?

Thanks for you advice in advance!

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915107/dagger2-androidtest-error-duplicate-entry-javax-annotation-generated-class

Comment: @piotrek1543 I use gradlew with version 2.14.1 so the solution for the mentioned question doesn't apply here I think

Comment: Part1. Two application are created for instrumentation tests execution. Application under test (basically it's your app). And separate application which contains your tests. I would say it's impossible to "include tests into app". See https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line.html "Running tests with ADB" for more information. Part2. Try to compile  release app and start tests via ADB, but I'm not sure if it will work. Probably Espresso needs debug version. Part2 is just a guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't compile the tests into the app APK, but you can test against the release build type. In your case your release artifacts would consist of two APKs, the regular app APK and the test APK. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064368/1231827.

Comment: thanks for clearing the misconception on my side. the solution is to just change the test build type to release. simple as that...